# PHP Returning JSON with modified data

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I want my categories list be nice formatted while return to user. What I get from database is:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "pet",
    "parent_id": null
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "page",
    "parent_id": null
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "dog",
    "parent_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "cat",
    "parent_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "rodent",
    "parent_id": 1
},...
```

I want it to keep tree structure, like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "pet",
    "parent_id": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "dog",
            "parent_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "cat",
            "parent_id": 1
        },...
```

etc.

Is there an easy way way to do it or I have to loop through the database results and create new organized array to return?
What is the best approach to do that? The problem is that the subcategories could also have subcategories. Or maybe i should just keep structure I get from the database and add children id's as an array (as I can refer to them anyway)?

I would be grateful for your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Since the relationship you describe is nothing that is built into php in form of data types or such you have to create the tree structure yourself. Simply because you have to describe the algorithm by which to build it.

Comment: im using lumen (laravel) framework (newbie in it). can it be build in category model?

Comment: Can we see the code in your controller that returns that?

Comment: yes, but what for? :P
$categories = response()->json(Category::all()); or
$categories = DB::table('categories')->get();
both gives same response.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
function normalize_db_animals(){

    $values[] = ["id" => 1, "name" => "pet", "parent_id" => null];
    $values[] = ["id" => 2, "name" => "dog", "parent_id" => 1];
    $values[] = ["id" => 3, "name" => "cat", "parent_id" => 1];
    $values[] = ["id" => 4, "name" => "rodent", "parent_id" => 1];

    $values[] = ["id" => 5, "name" => "wild", "parent_id" => null];
    $values[] = ["id" => 6, "name" => "tiger", "parent_id" => 5];
    $values[] = ["id" => 7, "name" => "rhino", "parent_id" => 5];

    $normalize = function () use ($values) {
        $tree = [];
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $pet = $values[$i];
            if ($pet['parent_id']) {
                if (array_key_exists($pet['parent_id'], $tree)) {
                    $tree[$pet['parent_id']]['children'][] = $pet;
                }
            } else {
                $tree[$pet['id']] = $pet;
            }

            $i++;
        } while ($i < count($values));

        return $tree;
    };

    $tree = $normalize();
    echo json_encode($tree);
}
```

**Result:**

```
   {"1":{"id":1,"name":"pet","parent_id":null,"children":[{"id":2,"name":"dog","parent_id":1},{"id":3,"name":"cat","parent_id":1},{"id":4,"name":"rodent","parent_id":1}]},"5":{"id":5,"name":"wild","parent_id":null,"children":[{"id":6,"name":"tiger","parent_id":5},{"id":7,"name":"rhino","parent_id":5}]}}
```

Comment: this one won't work if there were e.g. cat or dogs categories (and there will be)

Comment: I didn't understand your response, could you enlight me a bit more? If you refer that it will be nested categories same as: cat and dog, acting as parent categories, you should refine the solution looking for recursion. Encapsulate the closure into this function (array_walk_recursive): http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: Or make traditional recursive callback passing: normalize_db_animals($branch), where $branch could be the sub-array marked by current iteration and declare a $normalized_tree array that keeps pushing desired data. You should comment json_encode() inside then and return $tree. Beware of parents and children with the same name and classification, perhaps you shoud add another property, as uuid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$a = json_decode('[{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "pet",
      "parent_id": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "page",
      "parent_id": null
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "dog",
      "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "cat",
      "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "rodent",
      "parent_id": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "rodent",
      "parent_id": 2
    }]');

    $a = collect($a);

    $filtered = $a;

    foreach ($filtered as $key => $value) {
      $children = $a->where('parent_id', $value->id);
      if(!$children->isEmpty()){
        $value->children = $children;
       $filtered->forget(array_values(array_keys($children->toArray())));

      }

    }
    dd($filtered);
```